# geom_bar percentage for each group in x

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to calculate the percentage of observations in `geom_bar` with `y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100`, it does not provide the percentage by each group in `x`. Here's an example:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl), 
               y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100,
               fill = factor(gear)),
           position = "dodge")
```

Here, the sum of the percentages of all bars for a given factor(cyl) is not 100%; instead you reach 100% when you add the percentages of all bars in all groups. For example, for the `factor(cyl)==4`, the proportions are 1/11, 8/11 and 2/11:  9% +73% + 18% = 100%, but the code above shows the percentages: 3.12%, 25% and 6.25% (the sum is not equal to 100% by group). How can I make it show percentages by groups?

Comment: You could the calculations outside of ggplot2 and then plot using the summary dataset.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for your comment. So, is there no way to do this in `ggplot2`?

Comment: `ggplot` is a plotting package that is nice enough to include some convenient functions for common data aggregations. When you're doing more complicated data manipulation, it shouldn't be a surprise that you need to turn to functions/packages made for data manipulation.

Comment: To get percentages within groups: `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); mtcars %>% group_by(cyl=factor(cyl), gear=factor(gear)) %>% 
         tally %>% 
         complete(gear, nesting(cyl), fill=list(n=0)) %>%
         mutate(pct=n/sum(n))`. The code also includes the `complete` function to add a row with n=0 for the missing level of `gear` within `cyl`. That way you'll get the same bar widths for `cyl=8` as for the other two levels of `cyl` when you plot the data.

Comment: @Gregor, My last question was about adding percentage labels but this one is about plotting percentages by group.

Comment: I inadvertently answered this when I answered your previous question, though I edited it out to match your question better. [You can still see the old version, though.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40250493/2)